# Explaining something simple

Tags: education, finance, percentages

This is a question about math not finance but i will use the following formula to illustrate:

A) Total return = Dividend yield + Price change

B) Price change = (1 + change in 'price over earnings multiple') * (1 + change in 'earnings')

C) Price change = Change in 'price over earnings multiple' + Change in 'earnings'

How can you explain that (C) is incorrect and (B) should be used instead given (B) will ultimately get you the correct answer?

Cheers!

Comment: Would matheducators.se be better?

Answer (score 0):

The question

> How can you explain ... ?

is neither mathematics nor finance. It's pedagogy. The answer depends on what the person to whom you are explaining already knows.

I would guess that in the example you give the best strategy might be to work through a particular numerical example, showing the price change calculated both ways. WIth the numbers the explainee might see why  (B) is correct.